# Placeholder text in comment box not re-populating

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

Initially, the comment text box is two sentences of place holder text.  If you start to type, and then delete what you have typed, only the first line of the placeholder text is re-populated.

[image: Abnormal comment box behavior GIF]

I seem to be able to reproduce this while commenting on any answer of mine on `OSX 10.12.5` with `Safari 10.1.1` (no extensions).  I can't reproduce in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on Chrome / Ubuntu.

Comment: No repro on Chrome Beta on Ubuntu GNOME.  What browser are you using and what version is it at?

Comment: Browser/Version/OS? Any add-ons? Have you tested this in a different browser?

Answer (score -1):

This is not happening on my system. Here I am able to get the two lines comment.

It may be possible that in your system it is not happening.

- Try after clearing the cache.
- try after updating the browser.
- Or check on another system also.

There is no such bug.

Comment: Just edited the question, I seem to be able to reproduce it while commenting on any of my answers.